# Having some Trouble with List adapter and its arrguments?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listactivity, listadapter

ProgressTask.java

```
 public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean>{
 private ProgressDialog dialog;
 private ListActivity activity;
 private Context context;

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 ListView lv ;

 private static String url = "http://api.cartperk.com/v1/supportedoperator";

 private static final String OPCODE="code";
 private static final String OPNAME="name";

 public ProgressTask(ListActivity activity) {
     this.activity = activity;
     context = activity;
     dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
 }

 protected void onPreExecute() {
     this.dialog.setMessage("Progress start");
     this.dialog.show();
 }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
    if (dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(context, jsonlist,
            R.layout.list_item, new String[] { OPCODE, OPNAME}, new int[] {
                    R.id.opcode, R.id.opname});

    activity.setListAdapter(adapter);
     lv = activity.getListView();

}

protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++)
    {
        try {
                JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
                String opcode = c.getString(OPCODE);
                String opname = c.getString(OPNAME);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                map.put(OPCODE,opcode);
                map.put(OPNAME,opname);
                jsonlist.add(map);
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

its showing error in the `list_item`, `R.id.opcode` , `R.id.opname` should i create a new XML file and write the code there or else will generate dynamically  my present layout file is as show below can you guys help me out

```
<RelativeLayout>
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

  <ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
<RealativeLayout>
```

Not Able to Understand.

Comment: If I want to Create a XML file can you give me an Idea how it should be

Comment: Please post your `list_item` xml and logcat if possible.

Comment: @user3263528 do you have a xml by the name `list_item.xml` in re/layout folder??

Comment: No i dont have list_item.xml

Comment: i asking how can i create it an XML on the basis of the java shown above

Comment: @user3263528 check my post

Comment: @AbhisheK6006 why did you unaccept my answer now? What is wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
should i create a new XML file and write the code there or else will generate dynamicaly my present layout file
```

Look at the constructor

```
SimpleAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to)
```

You need to have `list_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="51dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/opname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="72dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Edit:

I think you do not have a `ListActivity` in the first place.

Secondly your json is

```
[ // is a json array noder
{  // json object node 
    "operatorCode": "AC",
    "operatorName": "Aircel"
},
```

But you have

```
 private static final String OPCODE="code"; // should be operatorCOde
 private static final String OPNAME="name"; // operatorName
```

Keys are not matching the column names

Thirdly you do not have a json object at the top its a json array.

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity
{
     private ProgressDialog dialog;

     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
     ListView lv ;

     private static String url = "http://api.cartperk.com/v1/supportedoperator";

     private static final String OPCODE="operatorCode";
     private static final String OPNAME="operatorName";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        new TheTask().execute();
    }
    class TheTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try
            {
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             httpclient.getParams().setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
             HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
             HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
             String res = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
             JSONArray json = new JSONArray(res);
             for(int i=0;i<json.length();i++)
             {
             JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(i);
             String opcode = c.getString(OPCODE);
             String opname = c.getString(OPNAME);

             HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

             map.put(OPCODE,opcode);
             map.put(OPNAME,opname);
             jsonlist.add(map);
             }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, jsonlist,
                    R.layout.list_item, new String[] { OPCODE, OPNAME}, new int[] {
                            R.id.opcode, R.id.opname});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.show();
        }

    }

}
```

Snap

[image]

Comment: Thank you Very much it was help Full

Comment: @AbhisheK6006 problem not sovled?? why did you unaccpet??

Comment: No the problem did not slove it still its not displaying the JSON data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21695064/having-trouble-with-async-and-listadapter-can-you-help-out/21695241?noredirect=1#comment32801945_21695241

Comment: @AbhisheK6006 then post some more relevant info to solve the issue. With what you posted its not possible to solve. and post it here

Comment: Here is complete java code i posted for some other problem

Comment: @AbhisheK6006 this is the question asked. so post it here. I don't want to look at other post and to the question asked i ahve answered

Comment: I post the complete java code. Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @AbhisheK6006 check the edit it will work fine. make sure you declare the activity in manifest and have internet permission.

Comment: If you can send me the hole project it be useful as reference for me and to show others how it is done to my friends

You Can mail me project at abhishek.k.gowda@live.com

Thank You